# jQuery ajax reload until non-empty data

Tags: ajax

I have a function which loops ajax using setTimeout.  But I want it to stop when the success data contains stuff -- but keep looping if it is empty.  I thought something along these lines but this didn't work for me,

```
function update(url){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {some:data},
        success: function(data) {
            if(responseText.data=='') {
                setTimeout(update,5000);
            }
            if(responseText.data!='') {
                jQuery('stuff').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
update(url);
```

Comment: `if(data=='') {
                setTimeout(update,5000);
            }
            if(data!='') {
                jQuery('stuff').html(data);
            }`

Comment: Umm, yeah that worked.  Should have just tried it in the first place.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the `responseText`. It should be

```
if(data=='')
{
    setTimeout(update,5000);
}
else
{ 
    jQuery('stuff').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW I would also restructure your condition statement and use `else if`. It's just better syntax.

```
function update(url){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {some:data},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data=='') {
                setTimeout(update,5000);
            }else if(data!='') {
                jQuery('stuff').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
update(url);
```

Comment: True, I'll make the change